# Very Strange numbers from rand()

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm getting some very strange numbers from this function.

```
-(int)generateRandomNumber:(int)min:(int)max {
    int i = rand() % ((max + 1)- min) + min;
    if(i < min || i > max) {
        NSLog(@"WEIRD RANDOM CASE JUST HAPPENED");
        return [self generateRandomNumber:min:max];
    }
    return i;
}
```

Sometimes, vary rarely, it'll return a number like 1243512 when the min is something like 1 and max is something like 9.

As you can see, i've tried to stop it, but it just happened to me again right now after I tried this fix.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Edit I'm using  srandom(time(NULL)); on the current cocos2d scene `init`

Comment: I just ran your generator 10,000 times in a loop with min set to 1 and max set to 9 and never produced results above 9. Is it possible that you're inputting numbers that aren't ints?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's causing your issue, but I would strongly suggest using random() or arc4random() instead of rand(). They produce much much better random numbers.